# Put request.path to a url parameter in Django template

Tags: django, templates, path

I want to create a back button to a page which can be accessed with a link from another page. To do this, I want to put the first page's path to the link, and on the next page I can put it to the back button.

I have this anchor tag:
`<a href="{% url 'page' path=request.path %}">Go to page</a>`

When I try to go to the site I get the following error:

`Reverse for 'page' with keyword arguments '{'path': '/my_site/'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['notifications\\/(?P<path>[^/]+)\\Z']`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the url name of the first page,

```
path('first_page/', views.first_page, name='first_page'),
```

then you can simply use:

```
<a href="{% url 'first_page' %}">Go the page</a>
```

Otherwise, you must add the url of the previous page to the context of the second page's template in order to use that in that template. How to do that depends on your style. For instance, you can somehow keep a log of the visited pages on the client side or server side, and use that collection to determine the previous page.